# Why does tcl consider an empty string a double?

Tags: tcl

Quite confused about this one:

```
$ tclsh
% string is double {}
1
```

Why would tcl consider an empty string to be a valid double?

Comment: Good question! It's to do with historical reasons, and is one of the small number of genuine mistakes in Tcl's design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary:** It's a bit of a misdesign and was a place where the initial use-case was the wrong one, but we can't change it in 8.* (I'm not sure about Tcl 9.0; we still want to avoid *gratuitous* changes there).

---

The `string is` command was originally designed to support the Tk `entry` widget's validation options. These let the widget respond to typing (or focus changs) by checking whether the change made the widget be in a valid state, such as holding a integer. If you wanted that, you'd just do this:

```
entry $w -validate key -vcmd {string is integer %P} -invcmd {bell}
```

Then, if you pressed a letter key, say <kbd>A</kbd>, with the cursor in the middle of an integer, the edit would be rejected and the system would make a warning noise. Really easy.

There's only one slight problem. If you had selected all the text in the entry and the pressed a digit, the edit would *also* be rejected (if `string is` was strict by default). The problem is that there's an intermediate transition state in the edit where the old text is deleted but before the new text is inserted: the validation occurs *twice* in such a situation, once for the `delete` and once for the `insert`. (It has to be that way because of the way things are tied together under the hood.) That's a ***terrible*** user experience, so `string is` was made lax by default so that this use case would work.

It's not a decision I agreed with — it should have been the other way round, with you needing to request laxity in the test if you want it, which would have added very little overhead here while allowing other uses to be saner — but I was just an ordinary user at that point. I prefer to use a multi-stage validation in my forms, such as using keypress level validation as a soft validation that allows bad input while the user is part-way through using the form, and just indicates that it knows that problems exist anyway, via techniques such as adjusting background colours and disabling submit buttons. (But that's off-topic for your question…)

Library command design is tricky. It takes careful consideration of use-cases to get right. Sometimes we fail.

---

The problem originated in code that was external to Tcl and Tk in about the time of Tcl 8.1.0. *Most* of the patch that introduced this was very good (it also gave us commands such as `string equal` and `string map`) but this was an aspect that could have done with a little more cooking.

Comment: Maybe just state the so well-explained: Use the `-strict` mode unless one knows what's all the fuzz about, i.e.: `string is double -strict $testedValue`. This might not have been the OP question, but for the follow-up readers, it may be what they are looking for.